# css auto width floating issue

Tags: css, css-float, width, expand

Please check out this image

[image: CSS Problem]

```
<body>
   <div class="main>
      <div class="left">blah blah </div>
      <div class="right">blah blah </div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

CSS part:

```
 .main{min-width:1200px}
    .left{width:400px ; height:auto ; float:left }
    .right{width:auto ; height:auto ;float:left }
```

I hope friends, you have got an idea from the image. Please help me.

I am dynamically inserting data into `right` div and when its width exceeds `800px`, it comes down the left div. But instead of that I want a horizontal scrollbar to view the content. One solution may be, removing `float:left` from right div. But still it causes problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be more helpful if you could post a link to the page or create a fiddle (jsfiddle.net), so we can work on the problem.

Comment: I have created a fiddle, I dont want the right part to come down the left http://jsfiddle.net/vinay49/fbeJc/

Answer (score 0):

on floated elements, height:auto means the height of the content (the default for floated elements). try with height:100%